# How to use a temporary table with dynamic sql?

Tags: stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

Im want to use a temporary table with dynamic sql but i have an error saying that the column `Column, parameter, or variable #3: Cannot find data type MyTable. Must declare the table variable "@CountriesFound".`

Here's my code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sqlDynamic @countryId int
AS

CREATE TYPE MyTable AS TABLE ([countries] varchar(50));

DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @CountriesFound AS MyTable

INSERT INTO @CountriesFound(countries)
select Name 
FROM CountriesFound

SET @statement =
    'SELECT name, CASE WHEN (c.name IN (SELECT countries FROM @CountriesFound)) THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
             END as countryFound FROM Country c WHERE c.countryId = @countryId'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @statement,
            N'@countryId int, @CountriesFound MyTable READONLY', 
            @countryId = @countryId,
            @CountriesFound=@CountriesFound;
```

Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: I don't see `@PartsPlanned` anywhere in your code.  This error must be caused by some other code and not what you've shown us.   Why are you using dynamic sql for this anyway?   It's unnecessary and is only hurting your performance.

Comment: i changed to @CountriesFound

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting has nothing to do with dynamic sql.   You cannot create a stored procedure that uses a User-Defined DataType (`MyTable` in your example) in the same procedure that is going to create the TYPE.   The TYPE has to already be created before the procedure will even let the code compile.

Consider this simplified code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TypeTest
AS 

CREATE TYPE MyTable AS TABLE ([Id] int);

DECLARE @mt AS MyTable;
```

Just executing this will give the error:

> Msg 2715, Level 16, State 3, Procedure TypeTest, Line 1 Column,
>   parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type MyTable. Parameter or
>   variable '@mt' has an invalid data type.

You need to CREATE the TYPE outside of the procedure code before you try to create the procedure.   It doesn't make sense to CREATE a TYPE inside a procedure code, since TYPE objects are permanent on the server until they are dropped anyway, and procedures are usually created to be run multiple times.

It would be nice if the SQL Server gave an error message more to this effect, but SQL Server isn't famous for having the most helpful error messages.